# Cant see Bootstrap-hamburger-menu icon in my header, and parts of nav-list-items ends up under logo-image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first post ever. I am pretty new to coding, and this is what i got so far for my header. 
Problem is, there is no hamburger-menu-button showing at all, and parts of the ul is ending up below my logo-image.
I have tried for two days to figure out what seems to be the problem, but I am just to much of a beginner to find the solution on my own.
Forgive me if i am posting this code wrong (i dont know why the code is colorless)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $("body").addClass("sleek");
      }
      else{
        $("body").removeClass("sleek");
      }

    })
```

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

body {
 background-color: #E8E8EE;
 padding-top: 130px;
 }

.header_wrapper {
 border-bottom: #d89766 2px solid;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #1d1a3d;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1050;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 height: 90px;
}
.sleek .header_wrapper {
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #1d1a3d;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1050;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 55px;
 }
.brand {
 max-width: 200px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 margin-top: -1px;
 }
 .sleek .brand {
 max-width: 160px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 margin-top: 2px;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav.navbar-nav a{
 float: left;
 color: #f5f5f5;
 font-size: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}
.sleek .nav.navbar-nav a{
 color: #f5f5f5;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: -3px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Header -->
<header class="header_wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="bilder/logo1cropped.png" class="brand">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Speltips</a></li>
          <li><a href="oddsbonusar.html">Oddsbonusar</a></li>
          <li><a href="tv-matcher.html">TV-matcher</a></li>
          <li><a href="casinobonusar.html">Casinobonusar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<!-- Header -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content_wrapper">
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
      </div><div class="content_wrapper">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
    </div><div class="content_wrapper">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
  </div><div class="content_wrapper">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <div class="content_wrapper">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div><div class="content_wrapper">
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div><div class="content_wrapper">
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the hamburger menu button to show on scroll?

Comment: Yes, i want the button to show whenever the screensize gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling and Resizing the view port are a little different but I have put a JSFiddle together [here](https://jsfiddle.net/afk60jrr/3/).

A couple of bits:

- As you are using bootstrap and with what you are trying to do you can stick a little closer to their standards.  I have just adjusted the html to that end.
- I have however add some css to override the `background: transparent` styles to border your button and produce the "burger" and
- I have had to add a little jQuery because the onClick was messing up.  No idea why.

Its not perfect but I hope it helps you out.  To get your nav to disappear and the button show, shrink your screen horizontally.